# How does this specific set look like?

Tags: general-topology

How does the set $  \begin{pmatrix}
        \cos(x) \\
      4\sin(x) \\
        \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb R ^2$ with $x \in \mathbb R$ look like?

I guess it should be similar to $f(x) = \arccos(4\sin(x))$ , but none of the programs I know like to plot that

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric+%28cos+t%2C4sin+t%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that $\binom{\cos x}{\sin x}$ is the unit circle.  Multiplying the second element by $4$ stretches that circle in the vertical direction by a factor of $4$, so it becomes an ellipse with minor axis $2$ and major axis $8$.

You can note that $\sin(\arccos X) = \sqrt{1-X^2}$, then $4\sin(\arccos X) = 4\sqrt{1-X^2}$.  However, since $\arccos$ has range $[0, \pi]$, this only gives you the upper part of the ellipse.

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice ellipse. By the way, $\arccos(4\sin(x))$ is not well defined as the domain of $\arccos$ is $[-1,1]$.

Comment: "That is a nice ellipse you got there, would be a shame if something was to happen to it" :P

Answer (score 0):

Well, $X = \cos x, \space {Y \over 4} = \sin x$, so $X^2 + {Y^2 \over 16} = 1$, so won't it be an ellipse?

Answer (score -1):

The topological space is basically homeomorphic to $S^1$

Comment: True, but unless you're a topologist, that won't be a satisfying description of what it looks like. :-)

Comment: How sad I am a topologist :P

Comment: Why is that sad?  Now you're satisfied! :-P

Comment: Topologists are easily satisfied. :)

Comment: We are :P Although I lean more toward algebraic topology